# Second `for` loop does not work in Java program

Tags: java

I am writing a `for` loop in Java. However, the second for loop does not work.

Input `5 4 3 2 1`
Expected output on for loop #1 `5,4,3,2,1,`
Expected output on for loop #2 `1,2,3,4,`

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arrayNumber = new int[10];
        int numbers;

        System.out.println("Put number here: ");

        for (int i=0; i<arrayNumber.length; i++){
            numbers = scan.nextInt();
            arrayNumber[i] = numbers;
            System.out.print(arrayNumber[i] + ",");
        }

        //This Code Does not execute!
        for (int i=arrayNumber.length-1; i>0; i--)
            System.out.print(arrayNumber[i] + ",");

    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Put number here: 
5 4 3 2 1
5,4,3,2,1,
```

Comment: Your array has ten elements, and thus you loop ten times in your first loop, so why are you only expecting to give it five ints?

Comment: Input `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` output `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,`. NOTE(s): No `System.out.println()` between loops. And `i >= 0` in the second loop condition.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, the desired output is `1,2,3,4,5` if the input is `5,4,3,2,1`, unfortunately, you cannot do this with array as it will output `0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5` because array is fixed at size 10 and initialized with zeroes initially.

You want to use [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) instead.

Side note:

- In the second loop, you are checking `i > 0`, this means the 1st element (at index 0) would never be printed.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> arrayNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Put number here: ");

        while (scan.hasNext()){
            if(!scan.hasNextInt()){
                break;
            }
            int numberInput = scan.nextInt();
            arrayNumbers.add(numberInput);
        }
        System.out.println("Received input: " + arrayNumbers);

        //This Code Does not execute!
        for (int i=arrayNumbers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) // should be >= 0 as you want to read first
            System.out.print(arrayNumbers.get(i) + ",");

    }
```

if you want to read an entire line `5 4 3 2 1` as input, then you don't use a loop to read the inputs, you use `scan.nextLine()` instead.

```java
// reads in a string of number separated by spaces
System.out.println("Enter a line of integers, separated by spaces: ");
String input = scan.nextLine()

// split the input string into an array of Strings
String[] arrayNumbers = inputLine.split(" ");

// continue with your first for loop to convert array of string into ints
```

Comment: There's no point of closing the Scanner; closing `System.in` is not generally helpful.

Comment: @Unmitigated you're right, thank you for pointing that out, learned something new today. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> //This Code Does not execute!

This is how `Scanner.hasNextInt()` works, it waits for more data and does not immediately returns false. You could break this waiting with Ctrl+D or by adding a letter instead of digit which would execute the break statement. But I suppose this is not what you are after, you want to read one line and then go straight to the second loop? If so I suggest reading an entire line first, and then parsing it. This will also fixt the problem with array length:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Put number here: ");

    String line = scan.nextLine(); //read entire line
    String[] numberStrings = line.split(" "); //split by space
    int[] arrayNumber = new int[numberStrings.length]; //initialize array, or use ArrayList<Integer>

    for (int i = 0; i < numberStrings.length; i++) {
        arrayNumber[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrings[i]);
        System.out.print(arrayNumber[i] + ",");
    }

    System.out.println();
  
    // in your original code you had:
    //  for (int i=arrayNumber.length-1; i>0; i--)
    // the fact that you had `i>0` caused that you would miss the first element

    for (int i = arrayNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(arrayNumber[i] + ",");
    }

    scan.close(); // release resources

    // Always release resources, you may also use try-with-resources:
    // try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // }
    // This way your resource is released also in case of exception
```

If you would like to learn about more modern use of java, then see below stream code version. Streams are new paradigm in java programming where instead of doing things more in a procedural way as in above code, you do it functionally:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Put number here: ");

    String inputLine = scan.nextLine();
    int[] arrayNumber =
            Arrays.stream(inputLine.split(" ")) //split the input
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) //convert each string to int
                    .toArray(); //turn stream into an array

    //first for loop output
    String output1 = Arrays.stream(arrayNumber)//turn array into stream
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf) //convert each int to string
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));//join them with a comma
    System.out.println(output1 + ",");

    // Second for loop output
    // To iterate from the end of the array, I use the IntStream.range() to generate indexes
    String output2 = IntStream.range(0, arrayNumber.length)
            .map(i -> arrayNumber[arrayNumber.length - i - 1])//for each index, get the value from the array buf in reverse order
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)//convert each int to string
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));//join them with a comma
    System.out.println(output2 + ",");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter numbers separated by spaces:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] numberStrings = input.split(" ");

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String numberString : numberStrings) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
            numbers.add(number);
        }

        // Print the numbers in the same order as they were input
        System.out.println("Output for loop #1:");
        for (int number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); // Print a newline to separate the output.

        // Reverse the list and print the numbers in reverse order
        System.out.println("Output for loop #2:");
        Collections.reverse(numbers);
        for (int number : numbers) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> *I am writing a `for` loop in Java. However, the second for loop does not work*
>
> ```java
> //This Code Does not execute!
> for (int i=arrayNumber.length-1; i>0; i--)
>   System.out.print(arrayNumber[i] + ",");
> ```

This is because the *arrayNumber* array can hold *10* elements and your input is only *5*, *"5 4 3 2 1"*.

Thus, during the initial *for-loop*, which is conditional to *arrayNumber.length*, the *nextInt* call will *[block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing))* and wait for an input for anything over *i = 4*.

Here is the *[Scanner#next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* *JavaDoc*,

> ***next**
>
>
>
> *public String next()*
>
>
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. ... This method may block while waiting for input to scan ...*

As a recommendation, utilize a *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))* on a *[Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* call, and parse each value.

```java
String[] a = scan.nextLine().split(" +");
arrayNumber = new int[a.length];
int i = 0;
for (String s : a)
    arrayNumber[i++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
```